# what type of projects exist to php none framework for xss filltering and security

Tags: php, security, xss

What type of projects exist to php  none framework for xss filltering and security?

I know there is [***OWASP ESAPI for PHP***](http://code.google.com/p/owasp-esapi-php/)
but its hardly update and not seem good as well i looking for something that can give good solution for security part for input filter and not just this.
i looking something that is best practice hehe,

as well if someone have good tips around security  so if have nothing so i know what to do here.

Comment: What is a "php none framework"? And I must admit I have problems understanding your question. And can you please explain what it is not "good"? So it might be easier to actually understand what your criteria are.

Comment: simple i got system that its not under of mvc atm that why  i been come here so its beed be work as standalone project unlike framework that need alot of stuff jsut get at to work in some case

Comment: Please correct your question, it's not clear what you mean. Also please run a typo-checker in your browser, not that I'm good in english, but reading your texts *hurts* even for me as non-native-speaker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try http://htmlpurifier.org/